# Calculate Average Age from a list of dates using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of dates where I want to calculate the average age.  I'm not sure what the best way of doing this using LINQ.

```
2017-04-13 08:31:00.000
2017-04-12 07:53:00.000
2017-04-11 07:59:00.000
2017-04-10 08:16:00.000
2017-04-09 15:11:00.000
2017-04-08 08:28:00.000
2017-04-06 08:26:00.000
```

Should I convert the date values to ticks and then calculate the average?

Comment: Enumerable.Average() does not work with DateTime or Timestamp. You will have to convert them all to UNIX time (ticks) and calculate that way.

Comment: What do you mean by "average age"?

Comment: So I get the age of each date and then get the average of that age. Make sense?

Comment: "age" is relative - do you mean the difference between that time and the current time?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I mean.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I convert the date values to ticks and then calculate the average?

No need - you can subtract two `DateTimes` and get a `TimeSpan` that will give you the difference between them in whatever unit you want. Just get the number of days (including fractions) between now (or whatever reference date is appropriate) and each item and average them:

```
double avgDays   = list.Average(dt => (DateTime.Now - dt).TotalDays);
```

Comment: There is no `TimeSpan.TotalYears` that I can see?

Comment: @NetMage Correct. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ's Average function.

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> timeSpan = new List<DateTime>()
{
    DateTime.Parse("2017-04-13 08:31:00.000"),
    DateTime.Parse("2017-04-12 07:53:00.000"),
    DateTime.Parse("2017-04-11 07:59:00.000"),
    DateTime.Parse("2017-04-10 08:16:00.000"),
    DateTime.Parse("2017-04-09 15:11:00.000")
};

DateTime average = new DateTime((long)timeSpan.Average(x => x.Ticks));
```

Comment: What does that have to do with "age"?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime`, internally, is represented by a specific number of ticks, that can be retrieved using the `Ticks` property. Since `Enumerable.Average()` does not work with `DateTime` and `Timestamp` types, you could proceed as follows:

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>()
{
    DateTime.ParseExact("2017-04-13 08:31:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("2017-04-12 07:53:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("2017-04-11 07:59:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("2017-04-10 08:16:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("2017-04-09 15:11:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
};

Int64 avgTicks = (Int64)dates.Select(d => d.Ticks).Average();
DateTime avgDate = new DateTime(avgTicks);
```

If by "age" you mean years and you are looking for a diff to the respect of the current year, then:

```
Int32 avgYear = DateTime.Now.Year - avgDate.Year;
```

If you want an absolute difference:

```
Int32 avgYear = Math.Abs(DateTime.Now.Year - avgDate.Year);
```

Comment: What he means by "age" is the difference from `DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score -1):

Using an extension method,

```
public static TimeSpan Average(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> spans) => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(spans.Select(s => s.TotalSeconds).Average());
```

You can compute the ages as `TimeSpan`s and get the average TimeSpan:

```
var now = DateTime.Now; // don't slide the ages by computational time
var avgAge = birthDates.Select(d => now - d).Average();
```

Or expand the extension method manually:

```
var avgAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(birthDates.Select(d => (now - d).TotalSeconds).Average());
```

Then you can use convert the `avgAge` to whatever units you need:

```
var avgAgeInYears = (avgAge.TotalDays/365.2425);
```